# PHP page load error 

Tags: php, html, forms, passwords, restriction

I'm trying to hide a content of a page using PHP but always get an error 
this is the code I'm using. Data from `$pass` comes from a form submited from the other page:

```
<?php
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];
 $password = "content";  // Modify Password to suit for access, Max 10 Char.
?>

<html>
<title></title>
<head>

<?php 
 // If password is valid let the user get access
 if ( "$pass" == "$password") {
?>

<!-- START OF HIDDEN HTML - PLACE YOUR CONTENT HERE -->
</head>
<body>
You have gained access!
<!-- END OF HIDDEN HTML -->

<?php 
 } else {
   // Wrong password or no password entered display this message
   print "<p align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\"><b>Restricted Area!</b><br>Please enter from the log in page</font></p>";}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Also, why are you comparing the variables as strings?  Why not just compare them directly?

Comment: The </head><body> shouldn't be inside a if() clause...

Comment: `"$pass"` and `"$password"` - the quotes are useless. `$pass == $password` will work the same. using quotes like that is evidence of cargo-cult programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link, your code didn't run and ended up with a fatal error simply because you had one extra `}` after the `print`, meaning your `else` ended with one too many `}`. Remove it and then your code will run without any errors:

[Online Working Example](http://codepad.org/pUiSFRwE)

In addition, if you compare variables, you must not use quotes `"`, try doing this:

`if ( $pass == $password) {`

Comment: it works thank you!!! just had a mistyped value on the form on the other page but thanks for the response!

Comment: I was happy to help you! Good luck to you, Link! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
print "<p align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\"><b>Restricted Area!</b><br>Please enter from the log in page</font></p>";}
```

On this line, you have an extra curly brace at the end. So in your file, you have an extra curly brace overall. 
Try changing this line to

```
print "<p align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\"><b>Restricted Area!</b><br>Please enter from the log in page</font></p>";
```

And it should work.